# GetContent root Web API .NET Core xunit ClassFixture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I'm trying to build a base fixture that will reside in its own *DLL* so that it can be used by many test projects.

I am having problems in setting the content root

```
.UseContentRoot(projectPath)
```

What I have below works but but I am hard-coding the `solutionName`.

Question

How can I get the contentRoot without hardcoding?

Can I inject anything in my baseFixture e.g. `IHostingEnvironment` or `solutionName`?

```
public class BaseFixture<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class
{

    public BaseFixture()
    {
        var startupAssembly = typeof(TStartup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var projectPath = GetProjectPath(startupAssembly);
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                   .UseContentRoot(projectPath)
                   .UseStartup(typeof(TStartup));

        Server = new TestServer(host);
        Client = Server.CreateClient();


    }


    private  string GetProjectPath(Assembly startupAssembly)
    {
        //Get name of the target project which we want to test
        var projectName = startupAssembly.GetName().Name;

        //Get currently executing test project path
        var applicationBasePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

        //Find the folder which contains the solution file. We then use this information to find the 
        //target project which we want to test
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBasePath);
        do
        {
            var solutionFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, "HardCodedSolutionName.sln"));
            if (solutionFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, projectName));
            }
            directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;
        }
        while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);

        throw new Exception($"Solution root could not be located using application root {applicationBasePath}");

    }

    public TestServer Server { get; set; }
    public HttpClient Client { get; }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Server.Dispose();
        Client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do a search for `*.sln` files to get the solution name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do a search for `*.sln` files while walking up the directory tree to get the solution name?

```
private string GetProjectPath(Assembly startupAssembly) {
    //Get name of the target project which we want to test
    var projectName = startupAssembly.GetName().Name;

    //Get currently executing test project path
    var applicationBasePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

    //Find the folder which contains the solution file. 
    //We then use this information to find the target project which we want to test
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBasePath);
    do {
        //find *.sln files
        var solutionFileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.sln").FirstOrDefault();
        if (solutionFileInfo != null) {
            return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, projectName));
        }                
        directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;
    }
    while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);

    throw new Exception($"Solution root could not be located using application root {applicationBasePath}");

}
```

Comment: Brilliant.I should have thought of that.

Comment: @developer9969 glad to help. I know the feeling. Sometimes all you need are some additional eyes on a problem to make things look a lot clearer ;) Happy coding!